# Where are my env vars located, other than .bashrc and .bash_profile?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, bash

I am trying to apply these env vars:

```
export ORACLE_OWNER=oracle
export ORACLE_SID=ORCL
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
export TNS_ADMIN=/home/romio
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

I tried to add them to my `.basrc` and `.bash_profile`, but they don't take effect. When I type `env` in my terminal, I will still see the old values, that were added from an ealier installation, which was done by someone else.

So my question, where could these old values be hiding, when they are not in my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

Comment: Did you `source` the file after adding those lines?, only then they are taken effect in the current shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything looks normal to me. Either you `env` on the new shell (not the current instance of terminal) or on your current shell, type in `source ~/.bashrc` and hit return if you have placed all the configurations in the bashrc.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I didn't know about the source, I'm farily new to unix

Comment: What if I had just rebooted the machine without sourcing, would it still not work?

Comment: rebooting machine automatically sources the bashrc. So it will work too.

Comment: @ishworkafley: It is not actually rebooting that makes it effect, upon the restart of the shell. The files `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are loaded at startup of every interactive shell. So the variables present are sourced to the current shell

Comment: @Inian thank you for the insight. Interactive bash shell invokes the .bashrc file, pretty much the same way when running vim session on terminal invokes its own config .vimrc .Knew the whole thing but never realised. Thank you again :) So rebooting whole system doesn't actually execute the .bashrc at start up!

Answer (score 1):

> It won't work, You need to **source** the file (`.bashrc`) after adding those lines; only then they are taken effect in the current shell.

A simple example,

```
$ echo 'export NAME="dude"'
export NAME="dude"    
$ echo 'export NAME="dude"' >> ~/.bashrc   
$ tail -1 ~/.bashrc
export NAME="dude"    
$ echo $NAME

$ env | grep -w NAME

$ source ~/.bashrc    
$ echo $NAME
dude
$ env | grep -w NAME
NAME=dude
```

See this wonderful example of [What is the difference between executing a bash script and sourcing a bash script?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip) for a better understanding.